# How could I write below summary more professional with good English

Tags: grammaticality

At beginner level I have learned a lot as a  developer and has closely observed development life cycle which results into  from past experiences. Now as a group lead I am managing and working  with team of 6 developers and also working as a independent resource .I am always working towards creating good vibrant environment to work with and has always work to handle stress full situations without creating a havoc. I am quick learner and a good
team player .Now I am interested in organizations which will be giving me challenging and creative opportunities as a frontend developer, full stack developer or leading a development team.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately we do not do proofreading here.

Comment: You can atleast give me  some suggestions

Comment: First you should stop saying *below* to mean *this*.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it is not the purpose here but could be of use for others. The OP understands their weakness and so could make use of some help.

State things in the present tense. Do not use "have" as in "have learned" just say "learned".
Not "am managing and working" but just "manage and work with". Not "am always working towards" but "always work towards".

Your sentences are generally too long with too many descriptors.
"I am always working towards creating good vibrant environment to work with 
and has always work to handle stress full situations without creating a havoc."

I cannot resist trying to help so here is an alternative.
"I always work towards creating a vibrant environment." 
 "I handle stressful situations without a problem."

The more you try to say things in past or past perfect the more likely it is to get it wrong and look bad.